# long data extending the limit of div

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem keeping long data within a divs boundary.

Here is the demo for which I am facing the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #main {
          width: 500px;
          margin:50px auto;
        }

        #data {
          width:500px;
          height:500px;
          border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="data"> TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here I make the div width `500px` fix but still the data is extending the div boundary.

Is there any solution that when the data reaches to the `max` width the remaining data displayed in the next line?

Comment: Possibly look into the css overflow property

Comment: I used the "overflow:auto" property, it provides the scroll in the div but the data still in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `word-wrap:break-word;` if you'd like the text to keep inside the div and appear on the next line.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/K54Uk/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

> Word-wrap property specifies whether the current rendered line should
>   break if the content exceeds the boundary of the specified rendering
>   box for an element (this is similar in some ways to the ‘clip’ and
>   ‘overflow’ properties in intent.) This property should only apply if
>   the element has a visual rendering, is an inline element with explicit
>   height/width, is absolutely positioned and/or is a block element.

This is a property introduced in CSS3 but it should work just fine for older browser.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tRhs3/)

Comment: Why post a dupe? If the correct answer's already been posted, upvote it instead of repeating..

Comment: I didn't say you copied and pasted, but you should upvote instead of posting duplicate answers. You've only just edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#data
        {
            width:500px;
            height:auto;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            word-wrap:break-word;
            overflow:auto;

        }
```